# rpm glibc Centos 7

Tags: centos7, glibc

How can I install both of them on CentOS 7? They both depend on each other. The machine is not connected to the internet.

```
[efe@localhost Desktop]$ sudo rpm -i glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc-common = 2.17-317.el7 is needed by glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64



[efe@localhost Desktop]$ sudo rpm -i glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    glibc = 2.17-317.el7 is needed by glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64
```

EDIT1: I have installed 2.17-292 for everything on x86_64 and it is successful. However, for i686 (yes, I need both unfortunately) I have tried to combine all packages into single command, lots of other dependencies appeared. I have tried to install 2.17-292 like I did for x86_64, this is the final output with errors. Before this last command, dependency errors appeared all the time, this is the first different error.

```
[efe@localhost packages]$ sudo rpm -i glibc-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686.rpm nspr-4.25.0-2.el7_9.i686.rpm nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.i686.rpm libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686.rpm libsepol-2.5-10.el7.i686.rpm pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686.rpm libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm 
warning: glibc-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
    file /usr/bin/ldd from install of glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive.tmpl from install of glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/share/gcc-4.8.2/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyc from install of libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
    file /usr/share/gcc-4.8.2/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.pyo from install of libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
```

EDIT2: I have entered a command as suggested by Florian Weimer.

```
[efe@localhost i686]$ sudo yum update *.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining glibc-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm: glibc-2.17-292.el7.i686
Package glibc.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Examining glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm: glibc-common-2.17-292.el7.i686
Package glibc-common.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Examining glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm: glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.i686
Package glibc-devel.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Examining glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm: glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.i686
Package glibc-headers.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Examining libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm: libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.i686
Marking libgcc-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm as an update to libgcc-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
Examining libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686.rpm: libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686
Marking libselinux-2.5-15.el7.i686.rpm as an update to libselinux-2.5-14.1.el7.x86_64
Examining libsepol-2.5-10.el7.i686.rpm: libsepol-2.5-10.el7.i686
Package libsepol.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Examining libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm: libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686
Marking libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.i686.rpm as an update to libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.x86_64
Examining nspr-4.25.0-2.el7_9.i686.rpm: nspr-4.25.0-2.el7_9.i686
Marking nspr-4.25.0-2.el7_9.i686.rpm as an update to nspr-4.19.0-1.el7_5.x86_64
Examining nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686.rpm: nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686
Marking nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686.rpm as an update to nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64
Examining nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.i686.rpm: nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.i686
Marking nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.i686.rpm as an update to nss-util-3.36.0-1.el7_5.x86_64
Examining pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686.rpm: pcre-8.32-17.el7.i686
Package pcre.i686 not installed, cannot update it. Run yum install to install it instead.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.8.5-36.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc(x86-64) for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade all the packages at the same time, using a command like this one:

```
sudo rpm -U glibc-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-common-2.17-317.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Or you can use `yum update`, like this:

```
sudo yum update --disablerepo="*" *.rpm
```

This has the advantage that packages not installed are not automatically installed by the upgrade (unless dependencies require it). `--disablerepo="*"` ensures that `yum update` does not try to download anything.

Comment: Please see Edit1.

Comment: Since I am not connected to the internet, does ```sudo yum update *.rpm``` work? Also, I have resolved the case for x86_64, this time problems appeared regarding i686. Thanks.

Comment: `yum update` does not need an Internet connection if the package set is complete. The `i686` case is basically handled the same way, by adding all required `i686` packages.

Comment: However, when I enter the command ```sudo yum -q list glibc``` I can only see the ```x86_64```, not ```i686```. I will try ```yum update``` now, and edit this comment.

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment. Can you please see edit2? I cannot understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

jlehtone in `forums.centos.org` solved my situation. I just needed to write

```
sudo rpm -i glibc-2.17-292.el7.i686.rpm nss-softokn-freebl-3.44.0-8.el7_7.i686.rpm nspr-4.25.0-2.el7_9.i686.rpm nss-util-3.53.1-1.el7_9.i686.rpm
```

[Link to forums.centos.org](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=77368&p=325241#p325241)